# MVC5 Asp.net Is there a way to get the correct value from EditorFor for a subclass

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class

```
public class Citizen
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long CityID { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public List<CitizenResource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

I want to edit individual items in the Resources but the EditorFor doesn't set up the input correctly.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Resources.Count; i++ )
{ 
    @Html.BeginForm("EditResource", "Citizen")
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p class="form-control-static">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Resources[i].Name)
                </p>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Resources[i].CurrentAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resources[i].CurrentAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <input type="hidden" name="ResourceID" value="@Model.Resources[i].ResourceID"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     }
}
```

What I get is name="Resources[0].CurrentAmount" which then doesn't map correctly to the CitizenResource class.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you creating multiple forms for each `CitizenResource` in the collection - its makes no sense because you can only post back one at a time. Either have one form to edit `Citizen` and all `CitizenResource` at once (and post back `Citizen`) or have a separate view to edit one `CitizenResource` and post back `CitizenResource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you sent causes that name:

> What I get is name="Resources[0].CurrentAmount" which then doesn't map
>   correctly to the CitizenResource class.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Resources[i].CurrentAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Instead have a partial view to edit an CitizenResource

```
@model CitizenResource

@using(Html.BeginForm("EditResource", "Citizen")){
            {
//The complete elements
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
//The rest of the elements
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating multiple forms which is not good. The best way to handle this kind of scenario is the use of EditorTemplates. Checkout this link on how to do it. [EditorFor() for a List of Complex Type (MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278362/editorfor-for-a-list-of-complex-type-mvc)