# Model properties are null after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have this model:

```
 public partial class Group
    {
        public Group()
        {
            this.ParameterGroup = new HashSet<ParameterGroup>();
        }

        public string GroupId { get; set; }
        public string Responsibility { get; set; }

        public virtual Text GroupDescText { get; set; }
        public virtual Text GroupNameText { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ParameterGroup> ParameterGroup { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Text
    {
        public Text()
        {
            this.ParamName = new HashSet<Parameter>();
            this.ParamDesc = new HashSet<Parameter>();
            this.EnumElemName = new HashSet<EnumElem>();
            this.IoDeviceInfoText = new HashSet<IoDeviceInfo>();
            this.IoCatText = new HashSet<IoDeviceInfo>();
            this.GroupDesc = new HashSet<Group>();
            this.GroupName = new HashSet<Group>();
            this.Type = new HashSet<Type>();
            this.ParamDispPath = new HashSet<Parameter>();
            this.EnumElemText = new HashSet<EnumElem>();
            this.TextValue = new HashSet<TextValue>();
        }

        public string TextId { get; set; }
        public string XmlId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Parameter> ParamName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Parameter> ParamDesc { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EnumElem> EnumElemName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IoDeviceInfo> IoDeviceInfoText { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IoDeviceInfo> IoCatText { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Group> GroupDesc { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Group> GroupName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Type> Type { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Parameter> ParamDispPath { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EnumElem> EnumElemText { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TextValue> TextValue { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Controller:

```
 public class GroupController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Group
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return PartialView("Index", GroupModel.Instance.getGroups());
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            Group group = KebaContext.SessionBasedContext().GroupSet.Where(g => g.GroupId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            List<Language> langs = KebaContext.SessionBasedContext().LanguageSet.ToList();
            foreach(Language l in langs)
            {
                if(group.GroupDescText == null)
                {
                    group.GroupDescText = new Text();
                    TextValue value = new TextValue();
                    value.TextId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                    value.LangId = l.LangId;
                    value.Value = "";
                    group.GroupDescText.TextValue.Add(value);
                }
                if (group.GroupNameText == null)
                {
                    group.GroupNameText = new Text();
                    TextValue value = new TextValue();
                    value.TextId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                    value.LangId = l.LangId;
                    value.Value = "";
                    group.GroupNameText.TextValue.Add(value);
                }
                if (group.GroupDescText != null && group.GroupDescText.TextValue.Where(x => x.LangId == l.LangId).FirstOrDefault() == null) //just one lang is available
                {
                    TextValue value = new TextValue();
                    value.TextId = group.GroupDescText.TextValue.First().TextId;
                    value.LangId = l.LangId;
                    value.Value = "";
                    group.GroupDescText.TextValue.Add(value);
                }
                if (group.GroupNameText != null && group.GroupNameText.TextValue.Where(x => x.LangId == l.LangId).FirstOrDefault() == null) //just one lang is available
                {
                    TextValue value = new TextValue();
                    value.TextId = group.GroupNameText.TextValue.First().TextId;
                    value.LangId = l.LangId;
                    value.Value = "";
                    group.GroupNameText.TextValue.Add(value);
                }
            }
            return View(group);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Group xyz)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Types");
        }
    }
```

This is my View:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@model Keba.Data.EF.Group
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Group Editing";
}
<h2>Edit Group</h2>
<div id="groupEdit">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Group", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupId);
        <table class="userEditAddTable">
            <tr><th>Responsibility</th><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Responsibility)</td></tr>
            @foreach (var name in Model.GroupNameText.TextValue)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => name.LangId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => name.Value)
                <tr><th>GroupNameText(@Html.DisplayFor(model => name.LangId))</th><td> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => name.Value)</td></tr>;
            }
            @foreach (var desc in Model.GroupDescText.TextValue)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => desc.LangId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => desc.Value)
                <tr><th>GroupDescText(@Html.DisplayFor(model => desc.LangId))</th><td> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => desc.Value)</td></tr>;
            }
        </table>
        <br />
        <div id="buttons">
            <input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" class="button" />
            <input name="Cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" class="button" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Problem:

If I try to change the value of a Text in the group model e.g. GroupNameText.TextValue.Value send it to the controller (submit). The properties GroupNameText and GroupDescText are null.
I have also tried the solution with propertybinding (`[Bind(Include = "GroupDescText,GroupNameText")] Group xyz`) which also doesn't work

Comment: instead of the tags inside foreach try to have partial view which represent each element in your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remember that only properties that are posted (i.e. have a form input element representing them) will be populated.

Second, the names of the input elements must match up to what the model binder expects on post, or it will discard the values, as it won't know what to do with them. In particular, with enumerables, this means you need to use `for` loops rather than `foreach`, so that Razor can create the right name binding:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.GroupNameText.TextValue; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GroupNameText.TextValue[i].LangId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GroupNameText.TextValue[i].Value)
    ...
}
```

That will result in a name attribute like `GroupNameText.TextValue[0].LangId`, which the model binder should be able to bind appropriately, whereas your field names are currently just `LangId`, which is meaningless on post.

Comment: i have this code now @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GroupNameText.TextValue.ToArray()[i].Value), still doesn't work. TextValue is an ICollection so I can't use the indexers directly

Comment: You can't cast to an array within the `HiddenFor`. You're still not generating the proper field name, and I'm frankly surprised you didn't get a runtime error. Regardless, you'll need to be working with something indexable in the first place on your model. If you can't modify the model classes directly to accommodate that, then you'll need to use view models.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089916/mvc5-asp-net-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-correct-value-from-editorfor-for-a-subcla/33116928#33116928) similar to your approach is to have a list in the view, you might need to have partials.