# Razor MVC 5 - Edit a collection of items containing enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently having a problem with editing collections in the browser. I want to edit a view model that has 3 properties, an int, a string and a list of items.

Here's the code:

```
public class HospitalDoctorAttributions {
    public string HospitalID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public List<AmountOfWork> Attributions { get; set; }
}

public class AmountOfWork {
    public WorkAreaEnum Sector { get; set; }
    public decimal FullTimeEquivalent { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I want to edit the attributions by work sector, so I have made this editor template:

```
@model AmountOfWork

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Sector)

<tr>
    <td>@Model.Sector.GetDisplayName()</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullTimeEquivalent)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment)</td>
</tr>
```

Which is refered by a view:

```
@model HospitalDoctorAttribution

// [...] Editors for the first two properties in the model

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Work Sector</th>
        <th>Amount by FTE</th>
        <th>Comment (optional)</th>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Attributions.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Attributions[i])
    }
</table>
```

The AmountOfWork items' properties are correctly mapped when I open the view, but when I edit them, it appears that nothing is posted back to the controller. The Year and HospitalID are posted back to the controller successfully, however.

How to fix this?

Edit: Generated HTML Code

```
<tr>
    <input Value="0" data-val="true" data-val-required="Le champ Sector est requis." id="Attributions_0__Sector" name="Attributions[0].Sector" type="hidden" value="URGENCE" />
    <td>Urgence</td>
    <td><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ FullTimeEquivalent doit être un nombre." data-val-required="Le champ FullTimeEquivalent est requis." id="Attributions_0__FullTimeEquivalent" name="Attributions[0].FullTimeEquivalent" style="display:table-cell; width:100%" type="text" value="0,00" /></td>
    <td><input class="text-box single-line" id="Attributions_0__Comment" name="Attributions[0].Comment" style="display:table-cell; width:100%" type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input Value="1" data-val="true" data-val-required="Le champ Sector est requis." id="Attributions_1__Sector" name="Attributions[1].Sector" type="hidden" value="GERIARTRIE" />
    <td>Gériatrie</td>
    <td><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ FullTimeEquivalent doit être un nombre." data-val-required="Le champ FullTimeEquivalent est requis." id="Attributions_1__FullTimeEquivalent" name="Attributions[1].FullTimeEquivalent" style="display:table-cell; width:100%" type="text" value="0,00" /></td>
    <td><input class="text-box single-line" id="Attributions_1__Comment" name="Attributions[1].Comment" style="display:table-cell; width:100%" type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML that gets generated into your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditorFor() for a List of Complex Type (MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278362/editorfor-for-a-list-of-complex-type-mvc)

Comment: @krillgar done!

Comment: Your HTML has both a `Value` and `value` property. I would try without the HTML helper.

Answer (score 0):

MVC should automatically index the property using the Editor template, so it would be just editor for collection, and model binder will apply loop and name-index:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Attributions, "Name of the editor for Single Item if not the same as DataType")
```