# Empty POST model argument when using EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to submit a form that incorporates an `@Html.EditorFor` element. If I remove the `EditorFor` element, my POST controller argument passes data correctly, but once implemented, my entire model argument shows as `null` in the POST controller.

Here's the model I'm trying to pass:

```
public class Checkout
{
    public int CheckoutID { get; set; }
    public string Requestor { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRequested { get; set; }
    public List<CheckoutReceiver> Receivers { get; set; }
}
```

The form element on page:

```
@model PRI.Models.Checkout

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCheckout", "API/CheckoutRequest", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "pri-form" }))
{
    <div id="checkout-request">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div id="checkout-info" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckoutID)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Receivers)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input id="create-checkout-submit" type="submit" value="Confirm transfer" class="btn btn-danger right" style="margin: 10px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If I remove the `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Receivers)`, and add data to the `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckoutID)` then that passes correctly to my Post Controller, so obviously my EditorFor is messing things up:

Here's the POST controller (i put a breakpoint right after it enters this so I can check the `checkout` argument):

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("CreateCheckout")]
public Checkout Create(Checkout checkout)
{

    var request = new Checkout();

    return request;
}
```

Here's my CheckoutReceiver Editor template (removed some input elements for brevity):

```
@model PRI.Models.CheckoutReceiver

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Receivers"))
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CheckoutID)

    <h4 class="contact-header">@Model.ContactType</h4>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <span class="form-header">Last Name</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "box-customer form-control ignore", placeholder = "Last name" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <span class="form-header">First Name</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control ignore", placeholder = "First name" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <span class="form-header">Middle Initial</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, new { @class = "form-control ignore", placeholder = "M.I." })
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Where am I going wrong, and why is my `EditorFor` causing my `Checkout` POST argument to be null on submit?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you dynamically adding and removing `CheckoutReceiver` items in the view (which is what the `BeginCollectionItem` method is for), in which case, you use `@Html.Partial()` inside a `foreach` loop and pass each item to the partial. If not, remove the `BeginCollectionItem`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the question, apparently it had to do with trying to POST a complex model to an ApiController instead of a normal controller. I don't think I was formatting correctly but placing the action in a normal controller worked as planned

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278362/editorfor-for-a-list-of-complex-type-mvc). You should add an editor for an
    `IEnumerable<CheckoutReceiver>` instead of an editor for `CheckoutReceiver`.