# How to post data to controller from ASP.NET MVC Form and Webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I need some help for the following scenario.
I have defined a model like this

```
namespace Sample.Models
{
    public class ContModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Customer")]
        public string Customer { get; set; }

        public List<Orders> Orders_ { get; set;}
    }

    public class Orders
    {
        public string OrderId;
        public string OrderDesc;
    }
}
```

In my view, I'm showing name, code, customer using `Html.EditorFor`, and I would like to use a Webgrid for getting input for Orders.

These three fields along with rows entered in Webgrid to be posted to the controller.

Initially the data source for Webgrid will be blank, User should be able to enter rows in the Webgrid. I have tried multiple approaches, not succeeded.

Please provide some approaches/guidance to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated note: Your `Orders` class represents a *single* order, but has a *plural* name.  If you rename it to the more accurate term `Order` then you don't need that random underscore in your property name.  (Though you shouldn't need it now... At first glance I thought `Orders` was an inner class.)  Giving things meaningful and semantically accurate names will make your code easier to understand in the long run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditorFor() for a List of Complex Type (MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278362/editorfor-for-a-list-of-complex-type-mvc)

Comment: The above link should help you. End of day: view the _rendered_ output to find the pattern used in `form` field `name`s. Once you get the pattern, you choose however you want to build the front end  (re: dynamically add fields via Javascript).

Comment: @David, Thanks for the tip

Comment: @EdSF, your link helped. 

This link helped more [link] https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp.net-mvc-getting-default-data-binding-right-for-hierarchical-views